# How to Create multi level Json using Jobject in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to create multi level Json, Using `http://json2csharp.com/.` I created classes. But not sure how to use it.

```
public class MassPay
{
    public string legal_name { get; set; }
    public string account_number { get; set; }
    public string routing_number { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string trans_type { get; set; }
    public string account_class { get; set; }
    public string account_type { get; set; }
    public string status_url { get; set; }
    public string supp_id { get; set; }
    public string user_info { get; set; }
}

public class MassPayList
{
    public string oauth_consumer_key { get; set; }
    public string bank_id { get; set; }
    public string facilitator_fee { get; set; }
    public IList<MassPay> mass_pays { get; set; }

}
```

These are my classes and this is Json Format i want to create...

## there are extra elements...

```
{
"oauth_consumer_key":"some_oauth_token", 
    "mass_pays":[
    {"legal_name":"SomePerson1",
    "account_number":"888888888",
    "routing_number":"222222222",
    "amount":"10.33",
    "trans_type":"0",
    "account_class":"1",
    "account_type":"2"
    },
    {"legal_name":"SomePerson2",
    "account_number":"888888888",
    "routing_number":"222222222",
    "amount":"10.33",
    "trans_type":"0",
    "account_class":"1",
    "account_type":"1"}
    ]
    }
```

So far i have come up with below code..I am using JObject, and all others wer single level so it was pretty easy. but when it comes to two or three level its difficult.

```
public JObject AddMassPayRequest(MassPayList lMassPayList, MassPay lMassPay)
        {
            JObject pin = new JObject(
                new JProperty("legal_name", lMassPay.legal_name),
                new JProperty("account_number", lMassPay.account_number),
                new JProperty("routing_number", lMassPay.routing_number),
                new JProperty("amount", lMassPay.amount),
                new JProperty("trans_type", lMassPay.trans_type),
                new JProperty("account_class", lMassPay.account_class),
                new JProperty("account_type", lMassPay.account_type),
                new JProperty("status_url", lMassPay.status_url),
                new JProperty("supp_id", lMassPay.supp_id),
                new JProperty("status_url", lMassPay.status_url),
                new JProperty("user_info", lMassPay.user_info)
           );
            return pin;
        }
        public JObject AddMassPayRequestList(MassPayList lMassPayList, MassPay lMassPay)
        {
            JObject pin = new JObject(
                new JProperty("mass_pays", lMassPayList.mass_pays),
                new JProperty("bank_id", lMassPayList.bank_id),
                new JProperty("facilitator_fee", lMassPayList.facilitator_fee),
                new JProperty("oauth_consumer_key", lMassPayList.oauth_consumer_key)
          );
            return pin;
        }
```

Can some one help me how to do this..?

Comment: MVC already has  a built in method for this. In you controller, initialize a new instance of `MassPayList` and set its properties then `return Json(yourInstance);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you give example?? If thats ok ??

Comment: Its simply `MassPayList model = new MassPayList(); model.oauth_consumer_key = "some_oauth_token";` and ditto for other properties (including adding new `MassPay` to property `mass_pays`) and then in the controller - `return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. The `Json()` method correctly generated the json data for you. Note if its a POST method, then you can omit the second parameter of the `Json()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke So you want me to generate two JSON and combine them ???

Comment: I added all properties of mass pay, Hoe can i create multiple instance. i am not sure how many users user will pass.. Its not fixed... So if user passed three array then i have keep count of it.. and how i do that not sure

Comment: I don't understand your comment - if you have 3 `MassPay` , then add 3 instances of `MassPay` to your property `mass_pays`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I am close, Will post my code in 30 mins... if it works can you tell me how to improve it..

Answer (score 1):

if you're using ASP.NET MVC you just need to use the Json response action using your existing classes.

You could simply do something like this in a controller:

```
return Json(new { PoId = newPoId, Success = true });
```

or an actual concrete model class:

```
var _AddMassPayRequestList = new AddMassPayRequestList();
  ...
```

returning a populated instance of your `AddMassPayRequestList` class:

```
return Json(_AddMassPayRequestList);
```

Comment: @T McKeown I want to create JSON and the method I am using is not working.. Can U tell me how to write usinh Jobject.??

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got this answer, Its simple structure. Using this u can create any type of Json... It doesnt have to follow same structure..

The logic behind this is add things you want at start, create class and inside that properties you want to add into json.  SO while passign just add for loop and pass Object to the list.. It will loop through and create JSon for You..

If you have any doubts, let me know happy to help you

```
 public String ToJSONRepresentation(List<MassPay> lMassPay)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));

            jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jw.WriteStartObject();
            jw.WritePropertyName("oauth_consumer_key");
            jw.WriteValue("asdasdsadasdas");
            jw.WritePropertyName("mass_pays");
            jw.WriteStartArray();

            int i;
            i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < lMassPay.Count; i++)
            {
                jw.WriteStartObject();
                jw.WritePropertyName("legal_name");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].legal_name);
                jw.WritePropertyName("account_number");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].account_number);
                jw.WritePropertyName("routing_number");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].routing_number);
                jw.WritePropertyName("amount");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].amount);
                jw.WritePropertyName("trans_type");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].trans_type);
                jw.WritePropertyName("account_class");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].account_class);
                jw.WritePropertyName("account_type");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].account_type);
                jw.WritePropertyName("status_url");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].status_url);
                jw.WritePropertyName("supp_id");
                jw.WriteValue(lMassPay[i].supp_id);
                jw.WriteEndObject();
            }
            jw.WriteEndArray();
            jw.WriteEndObject();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```